# Positioning text relative to image

Tags: html, css, image, text

I am wanting to, if possible, align a set of text (`<p>TextHere</p>`) relative to where a image is. I have an image centered horizontally on my page:

```
.headerlogo {
    height: 60px;
    width: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    margin-top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -35px;
}
```

Now, I want some text to be 50px to the right/left of that... I thought there may be some sort of way to do so using something similar to `margin-left` but so far haven't come up with anything.
I know that I can put text a certain distance out from the left using `margin-left: 600px;` so that it looks good and next to the image, but as you all know, this will move on window resize.
Any help would greatly be appreciated as I am still new at positioning...

Comment: Post the relevant `HTML` code too.

Comment: where is the html code, jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

as you didn't post the relavent code of your problem but still i try to display the text next to the image with `margin-left:50px`. and it will not gonna move on windows resize .
Here is the jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/datechogeek/qU6Cb/

Answer (score 0):

Keep the **position:absolute** for your text and add left,right position as per your need . It would be nice if you can post your complete HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Were you trying something like this?

HTML

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <p class='leftText'>Left text</p>
    <img class='headerlogo' src='http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/media/p/2/000/19b/1b2/065601a.png' alt='your_image'/>    
    <p class='rightText'>Right text </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
    position:relative;    
    height:60px;
    width:280px;
    margin:auto;

}

.headerlogo {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height: 60px;
    width: 70px;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
}

.leftText, .rightText {
    position:relative;
    float:left
}
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ej8hU/)